# How to create web store on localhost in wamp with database

Tags: magento2, database, localhost, wamp

How can i create a web store in Magento 2 with database? I install Magento, i made a database which is now, after installation, full with all tables that are needed, but i have to do new database for my final work on university and there is the problem. I don't know how to join that. I read something about doing models with databases, is that it? Please, help me. I don't need to do some extra web shop, database and its functionality are important.

Comment: How to install Magento2 in your localhost? is this what you are trying to do and what your question is about?

Comment: No, my question is how to create a simple web shop/store with database and how it works, that database and Magento 2. And do i need to do anything more to create store by myself. I see how to do page and clicking and stuff, but i have to know more about db. Maybe about some files, which are important?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Magento to create your store. 
Once you installed it you are ready to use it.

This is an example of what you get once you install Magento2 (using sample products)

http://magento2-demo.nexcess.net/

Magento use a database to store and retrieve data (products, orders, customers, etc.)

Magento can easily reach 13.000 files/folders so it is difficult to say which one is important (I guess all of them).

Comment: Thank you very much! And just one question, is there something more i have to do with database? I know that i can change and add tables, but do i have to do anything else to create store?

Comment: To create a Magento2 store you only need to create an empty database and tell Magento the details of your database. After that Magento takes care of everything else.

Comment: Happy to help, and welcome to Magento Stack Exchange. Remember that If this answer or any other helped to solve your issue, it would be nice from you to mark it as accepted.